# Distinct year-months with Linq (to entities)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity set of Publications with a ReleaseDate property. I would like to get a List of all distinct year-&-month combos from this set for the purpose of creating a pagination widget.

Preferably, I'd like a list of DateTime values with the day as 1 for each distinct year-month  from my publications set:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> DistinctYearMonths = from p in context.Publications.  .... ?
```

How can I finish this linq-to-entities query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> DistinctYearMonths = context.Publications
    .Select(p => new { p.ReleaseDate.Year, p.ReleaseDate.Month })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList() // excutes query
    .Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1)); // copy anonymous objects
                                                    // into DateTime in memory
```

The intermediate step to project into an anonymous type is necessary because you cannot directly project into a `DateTime` (constructors with parameters are not supported in projections in LINQ to Entities and the `Year` and `Month` properties of `DateTime` are readonly, so you can't set them with initializer syntax (`new DateTime { Year = p.ReleaseDate.Year, ... }` is not possible)).

Comment: You win. And +1 for the good explanation -- all other answers here are similar in yielding the "System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```
(from p in publications
 select new DateTime(p.ReleaseDate.Year, p.ReleaseDate.Month, 1)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting "System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities." when I put this right into LinqPad -- any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Faust it means `ReleaseDate` wasn't initialized in the property itself. it's a good practice to init your POCO properties of type DateTime and List<myclass> like so:       `public virtual List<Profile> Followers { get; set; } = new List<Profile>();` and         `public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;`

Answer (score 1):

Using Group By:

```
(from i in context.Publications
group i by new { i.ReleaseDate.Year, i.ReleaseDate.Month } into g
select g.Key).ToList().Select(i => new DateTime(i.Year, i.Month, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var DistinctYearMonths = (from p in context.Publications
                          select new DateTime(p.ReleaseDate.Year,
                                              p.ReleaseDate.Month,
                                              1)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var DistinctYearMonths = context.Publications
    .Select(x => new DateTime(x.ReleaseDate.Year, x.ReleaseDate.Month, 1))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
```

I like chained linq methods much better than the long form. They're much easier to read IMO.