# linq Select distinct year sql date field

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, date, entity

I have a SQL table of records with date fields similar to

|----Date----|
  1/22/2016
  2/3/1986
  12/9/1992
  10/9/2016

I would like to do a linq to entity query to get an array of unique years eg

```
var years = {"2016", "1986", "1992"}
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011094/distinct-year-months-with-linq-to-entities) from a previous question will pull unique dates, but I need to translate into years only.

Comment: Do you already have an entity class? How does it look like?

Comment: The unexplained down vote is unnecessary. This question is already resolved and the respondents provided clear explanations on their answers. The question was clear enough for them to answer it. I would appreciate any non-constructive down votes directed elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your entity class looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int MyEntityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query would look like this:

```
var unique_years =
    context
    .MyEntities
    .Select(s => s.DateTimeProperty.Year)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `Year` property of the DateTime object before doing the Distinct()

```
var uniqueYears = db.Orders.Select(s => s.OrderDate.Year).Distinct();
```

Assuming `db` is the object of your DbContext and `Orders` is a property on your DbContext class of type `DbSet<Order>` and Order entity has an `OrderDate` property of type `DateTime`.

**Or** If you already have a list of `DateTime` objects.

```
var dateTimeList = new List<DateTime>();
var uniqueYears = dateTimeList.Select(s => s.Year).Distinct();
```

Comment: You should access `OrderDate` via the lambda parameter `s`, not directly on the `Orders` DbSet.

Comment: Yep ! . Thanks for noticing that